# Why pointers didn't work correctly in sorting two dimensional array?

Tags: c++

I use this code but it runs wrong. It sorts some of data right but the rest
don't get sorted properly.  I want to know where is the mistake in this code and why?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
const int row=4;
const int col=4;
int main()
{

  int mat[][col]={{1,2,3,4},{2,8,4,1},{3,5,7,8},{7,6,6,5}};
  int arr[row][col];
  cout<<" first "<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
         cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";
     }
      cout<<endl;
   }

  for(int i=0;i < row;i++){
     for(int j=i+1;j <= col;j++){
        if(*(*(mat + 0) + i) >= *(*(mat + 0) + j)){
             temp= *(*(mat + 0) + i);
             *(*(mat + 0) + i) = *(*(mat + 0) + j);
             *(*(mat + 0) + j) = temp;
         }
     }
  }

  cout<<" after arrangement "<<endl;
  for(int i=0;i<row;i++){
     for(int j=0;j<col;j++){
        cout<<mat[i][j]<<" ";
     }
     cout<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In your sort, `i` is never more than `3`.  `j` is never more than `4`.  You are only sorting the first five integers.

Comment: `(mat + 0)` is also a suspect expression.  Why keep adding zero to something?

Comment: why do you use pointers instead of referring with indexes such as `mat[i][j]`. It will be easier to read and debug.

Comment: Multiple problems. (1) In the inner loop, `col` reaches a maximum value of `4` so `*(*(mat + 0) + j)` uses an element that does not exist on the last iteration. (2) Usage of `*(mat + 0)` everywhere means your loops only ever affect the first row of `mat`. (3)The use  of a variable-length array (VLA) in `int arr[row][col]`, where `row` and `col` are variables, is invalid C++ (although some compilers, notably gcc allow this as an extension to C++). (4) Your data is in arrays, so better to use array syntax - obfuscating with pointer syntax makes debugging harder

Answer (score 0):

Be wary when accessing elements that they are within the bounds of the array.

The line `for(int j=i+1;j <= col;j++){`, is trying to access the `i+1`*st* element which doesn't exist when you loop to the last element in the array, so you can avoid this by looping to the second last element with `for(int j=i+1;j < col;j++){`.

Also, you will want to iterate the sort algorithm for each array in the 2D array.

So you could do something like this:

```
for(int n=0;n < row;n++){
    for(int i=0;i < row;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j < col;j++){
            if(*(*(mat + n) + i) >= *(*(mat + n) + j)){
                int temp= *(*(mat + n) + i);
                *(*(mat + n) + i) = *(*(mat + n) + j);
                *(*(mat + n) + j) = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the rules are for the sort you want, however, assuming any reasonably consistent sort is desired perhaps you will accept to cast your array to a single dimensional array or pointer and sort that way using a standard sort such as qsort or std::sort... There has been debate whether that induces undefined behaviour or whether the rules of array packing ensures that it's always well defined - if you believe the latter then this might be your answer.